# WPF UserControl exposing style?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

How do I expose a style as a property in a WPF USER CONTROL ?

I have a user control that has a textbox. Let's called this textbox "mainTextBox". Let's call my control "myControl".

I want the user of the control to be able to do something like :

```
<myControl mainTextBoxStyle={StaticResource someStyle} >
```

How do I do this and is it even possible ?

Regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a dependency property `MainTextBoxStyle` to your `UserControl` that is of the type `Style`.
In the constructor of your `UserControl` create a Binding from 'MainTextBoxStyle' to the `Style`-property of the `TextBox`.

Here an example for the binding:

```
mainTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.StyleProperty,new Binding("MainTextBoxStyle"){Source=this,Mode=TwoWay});
```